# Getting Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error for SonarQube with jdk 1.7

Tags: sonarqube, jdk1.7

I am using SonarQube version 5.5. My SonarQube server is running successfully on http://localhost:9000 on windows 64 bit.

I have one Maven project which is running on jdk 1.7 and its POM with Sonar server configuration is as shown below.

```
<properties>
 <java-version>1.7</java-version>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
<wsdl4j.version>1.4</wsdl4j.version>
<commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
<commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
<sonar.host.url> http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url> </properties>
```

When I run `mvn sonar:sonar`  command, it gives me below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:101)
```

I understand its java version issue but not able to figure out the solution.

Did any one face such an issue ?

Comment: The sonar-plugins only works with Java 8

Comment: SonarQube 5.5 itself still supports Java 7. Which plugin version do you have?

Comment: I started sonarQube 5.5 server, and it started with java 7.I am not using any eclipse pluging its SonarQube 5.5 downloaded zip file which I haveextracted. Putting the server startup echos below                                     ** >StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | 2017.06.08 16:06:59 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_91\jre\bin\java **

Comment: Wait. 52.0 _is_ Java 8. You are somehow trying to run Java 8 code in a Java 7 VM.

Comment: @Marvin - My POM contains Java 1.7 only and My environment variable is set to Java 7, I verified it with java -version command, and it says java 7. I am running the mvn commands from Command prompt, so it should take java 7 for compiling my code.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: And still your JVM tells you that it found Java 1.8 code. I cannot tell you where this might come from but I don't think it's lying ;)

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube Maven plugin being used supports only Java 8+. You should force an older version of org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin in your pom or in the command-line.